# Getting a final value from elements.all.each in the protractor library 4.0.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, promise, protractor

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a date array from an each loop AFTER it completes iterating.

Here's the code for context:

```
this.Then(/^The details should match with Splunk data$/,function(callback){
     var x=[];
     page0213.expandDate();
     page0213.myDates(function(id){                                
     x.push(id);        
     console.log("Test: "+ x);
     });        

     browser.pause();
     }
);
```

This function is calling a function called page0213.myDates which looks like this:

```
this.myDates = function(results){                
element.all(by.css('td[ng-bind^=dashboardSummary]')).each(function(date){
          date.getText().then(function(text) {
          results(text);
          });                                
     });                        
}
```

I've tried treating it as a promise (like this: ".each(...).then(callback())" ) and by moving the callback after the each (because some sources say that each should behave synchronously).

I've also tried Promise.promisify(elements.each) and then putting them into a Bluebird coroutine like this:

```
 this.getDates = Promise.coroutine(function*(){
    try{
           let dates = [];
           yield browser.waitForAngular();
           let elements = yield Promise.resolve(element.all(by.css('td[ng-bind^=dashboardSummary]')));
           return elements
    }catch(exception){
           console.error(exception);
           return "nothing was done"
    }
});
```

-

```
this.Then(/^The details should match with Splunk data$/,Promise.coroutine(function*(callback){
     var x=[];
     page0213.expandDate();
     x = yield Promise.resolve(page0213.myDates())                               
     console.log(x)

     browser.pause();
     })
);
```

But it only yielded a promise object, rather than a resolved value.

None of those methods have worked. I've been trying to fix this issue since yesterday.

Does anybody have any guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't return from the `myDates` function and the inner promise resolution functions. And, it sounds like you actually need to use [`.map()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map), not `.each()`.

But, I think you are overcomplicating the problem and just need to [call `getText()` on `element.all()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) which is often overlooked. It would return a promise resulting into an array of strings:

```
var summary = element.all(by.css('td[ng-bind^=dashboardSummary]'));
expect(summary.getText()).toEqual([ 
    "summary1",
    "summary2"
]);
```

If you want to see the values on the console:

```
summary.getText().then(console.log);
```